# Docker containers do not stop and get removed after a script has been executed

Tags: php, bash, docker

We are having a Docker server 'Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22'. We have a number of workers, around 10,each one of them performs a really simple task that takes a few seconds to complete and exit. We decided that every one of them is going to start a docker container and when the script finishes, the container gets stopped and removed. What is more, crontabs deal with running So, we created a bash script for every worker that instantiates the container with the flags --rm and -d and also starts the script file in the bin/ folder

```
#! /bin/sh
f=`basename $0` 
workerName=${f%.*} \\name of the bash script without the part after the .

//We link with the Docker host the folder of the worker and a log file that is going to be used for monitoring from outside the container.
docker run --rm -d --name $workerName -v `cat /mnt/volume-fra1-05/apps/pd-executioner/master/active_version`:/var/www/html -v /mnt/volume-fra1-06/apps/$workerName.log:/var/www/html/logs/$workerName.log iqucom/php-daemon-container php bin/$workerName

echo `date` $0 >> /var/log/crontab.log
```

So, we created a bash script for every worker that instantiates the container with the flags --rm and -d and also starts the script file in the bin/ folder. All the workers are very similar to the structure and the code and really simple, there are not big code differences. However, we have experienced the following behaviour: some containers (random ones every time) refuse to stop and be removed even after many hours. Inside the container, the process `php bin/$workerName` is still running with PID 1. There is nothing like an infinite loop in the code that could stop the script from finishing. It happens randomly and still cannot find a pattern. Do you have any idea on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can be some issue related to your PHP script getting stuck somehow. But since you are sure it is suppose to timeout after lets assume 240secs then you should can change your container command to

> docker run --rm -d --name $workerName -v `cat /mnt/volume-fra1-05/apps/pd-executioner/master/active_version`:/var/www/html -v /mnt/volume-fra1-06/apps/$workerName.log:/var/www/html/logs/$workerName.log iqucom/php-daemon-container timeout 240 php bin/$workerName

This will make sure that any stuck container will exit after a timeout if it doesn't exit on its own

Comment: Thank you for your input Tarun. I will definitely try it and come back to you. I have never faced this problem on my local machine.  All the scripts finish their execution flawlessly every single time when I execute them from the command line or through the usage of Docker containers.

Comment: Your answer @tarun-lalwani was on spot as it stops the containers after some time. However, I still have the underlying issue of why the php process (with pid 1) is not getting killed, thus not stopping the container. Question can be considered solved.